# ListView row set Left Margin programmatically in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, layoutparams

I have a ListView with its Custom Adapter.

in adapter's getview i want to set margin left of 15 dip to some rows. based on certain conditions.

```
  -----------------------------
 |  Row 1 (margin 15dip)       |
  -----------------------------

  -----------------------------
 |  Row 2 (margin 15dip)       |
  -----------------------------

       -----------------------------
      |  Row 2.1 (margin 30dip)     |
       -----------------------------

             -----------------------------
            |  Row 2.1.1 (margin 45dip)   |
             -----------------------------

  -----------------------------
 |  Row 3 (margin 15dip)       |
  -----------------------------
```

But when i set margin using the following code it gives `ClassCastException`

> 01-17 18:19:35.467: E/AndroidRuntime(14165):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Row layout

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <FrameLayout
>  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>  android:id="@+id/parentframeLayout"
>  android:layout_width="match_parent"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
>  android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="40dip"
>     android:background="@color/alphaBlueMariner"
>     android:gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/offlineImageView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_object_offline" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/parentImageView"
>         android:layout_width="@dimen/small_indicator_icon_square"
>         android:layout_height="@dimen/small_indicator_icon_square"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tvParentName"
>         style="@style/TextViewMedStyleShadowBlack"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:paddingLeft="20dip" />
> </LinearLayout>
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

sample in my getView method

```
   Log.i("LayoutParams","1");
            // setting left margin
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    );

            Resources r = context.getResources();

            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    15, 
                    r.getDisplayMetrics()
                    );

            if(requirementModel.getParentId() == 0)
            {

                params.setMargins(px, 0, 0, 0);

                parentFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            }
            else
            {

                params.setMargins(px+px, 0, 0, 0);

                parentFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            }
            parentFrameLayout.requestLayout();

}

return row;
```

this code runs but crashes when

> return row;

Please help. thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ListView expects AbsListView.LayoutParams that does not support margins. Try to set margins on the LinearLayout object instead of the FrameLayout. Or use paddings on the FrameLayout.

Comment: now i've set padding to the framelayout object.
Thanks it works

Comment: Setting the LayoutParams on the nested view worked for me.. i had a LinearLayout as the "main" view, this main layout has a child LinearLayout that holds all of the items content. 
When trying to apply a margin to the Main LinearLayout, i would get the ClassCastException.
When i applied the margin to the child LinearLayout, everything worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because LayoutParams is not LinearLayout type. Can you try this?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the list view params to and do your job if you want to set margin in complete view but individual item margin can be set as suggested by others

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mListView
        .getLayoutParams();

marginLayoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, righttMargin, bottomMargin);
```